# c# ClickOnce Куда сохраняется бд SqLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, clickonce

При публикации через ClickOnce, не понимаю куда сохраняется БД
Если через обычный делать, БД вижу. А если нет - не понимаю куда

Comment: Вангую где то в `%AppData%`

Comment: Она у вас в каталоге с программой создается, или как? Выполните в опубликованном приложении код типа `MessageBox.Show(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));`, чтобы узнать, куда оно устанавливает. Там будет типа `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`, возможно, где-то там БД и будет.